# django combining forms with elements from a list in a table

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have the following problem. I am trying to create a form like a 2D array where you can input values for several characteristics on several objects. This resulted in a formset of forms for the individual objects displayed in a table with the individual forms displayed horizontally.

My template looks like this at the moment: `

```
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
        <thead><tr>
        <th></ th>
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr></thead>
    {% endif %}
    <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">

    <td>  {{ ?? }}  </ td>

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <td>
        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden.name }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
        {{ field }}
        </td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`

This is code that was taken from the net btw. Now what I would like to do is somehow put a column in front of the table with just some text stating the name of the object, however i can't seem to do it.

I have tried to add them from a list, but then the problem is that it is not possible to access the right element from the list. Looping through the list results in the same problem.

I also tried adding a hidden field to the forms, setting the value of that field in the view, and then trying to recover it using something like 
 `form.my_field.value` but i can't seem to actually get the value from the field. I did manage to get the name of the field, but the value just was not possible.

I can imagine doing this using some javascript but that is really a last resort. It seems to me that something as basic as this has to have a nice serverside solution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.3, you can render the [raw value of a form field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value).  Assuming you want to render the value of a field called `name`:

```
{{ form.name.value }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was still in 1.2.3, that is probably why it wasn't working. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there could be fews solutions, one will be to use existing field properties like `name` or `description` - then data will be bindend with the field itself.

you can add custom properties to the form fields and reference them in the code.

or use a custom template tag, which will return a text when field name will be passed as a parameter:

```
NAMES = {
    'field1': u'my description1',
    'field2': u'smthg else'
}

@register.simple_tag
def get_text(name):
    return NAMES.get(name, u'--no description--')
```